# How to solve 504 http error on azure devops?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-logic-apps

I have created a logic app for my azure pipeline automation. Inside the logic app I have used the Azure Devops http connector to send request to azure devops via REST to queue a defined pipeline with specific parameters.
I see that whenever the connector is executed, the respective pipeline gets triggered but it keeps on getting triggered until and unless the connector throws a 504 error and fails the logic app. But the pipeline runs successfully as the parameters that are passed through the logic app to Azure DevOps are valid. Any solution to this problem?

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

As workaround, you can try to use **Queue a new build** action in Logic Apps Designer.

[image]

Comment: Yes but wouldn't that be taking my username in the requestedFor property of the Json schema? If I wanted to give there another Id let's say Microsoft.VisualStudio.services.TFS?

Comment: Yes,in the `queue a new build` action, we can only define the parameter but not the request body. `it keeps on getting triggered` For this ,you can check if any trigger is always triggering the pipeline.